# mysql installation issues - mac osx

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I've recently attempted to install mysql on my mac - osx lion.

I followed this guide - http://matthom.com/archive/2009/06/14/installing-mysql-mac-os-x

I can't seem to create a database from terminal, so I assume I've done something wrong in my installation.

When I try -

```
mysql> create database some_name;
```

I get -

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'some_name'
```

Also, I've tried to install phpmyadmin, but it won't let me log in. I get -

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to get away from using mamp.

Comment: Did you follow the steps under the heading *Adjust MySQL root password*?

Comment: I did, and I just changed it to make sure. It seems to have changed the password, but I still can't create a database.

Comment: You're not actually logged in to the client as root, you need to start the MySQL client with `mysql -u=root -p`. It might be spaces instead of `=`, can't remember off the top of my head. Run `mysql --help` for more info.

Comment: @DaveRandom Don't type in the password as program parameter, as this will be stored in `~/.bash_history` or similar files. Just leave the password-parameter without the password, this will cause MySQL to (securely) prompt for a password.

Comment: @feeela Good point well made, edited that part out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MySQL via the console, you need to log in first:

```
$ mysql --user=root --password
Enter password: 

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `some_database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
```

Also, when using PHPMyAdmin, you maybe need to manually [set up the login method](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types).

Answer (score 0):

If you run this on mysql:

```
CREATE USER 'your_mac_user'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'your_mac_user'@'localhost';
```

You can access mysql command-line with all privileges by simply writing "mysql" on terminal.